# How can I calculate the profitability of this dash cloud mining contract?

Tags: mining-profitability, cloud-mining, dash

I'm looking at a cloud mining contract by Genesis Mining at $500 for two years mining with 100 MH/s for Dash. The current network hashrate is 2550 MH/s. The mining reward is 3.6 dash per block, and there were 550 blocks in the last 24 hours. How can I calculate when I'll break even and how much profit I could possibly make over the duration of the two years assuming these factors remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make cloud mining contracts! A lot of cloud mining providers are just scammers.

The network's cumulative hash rate of Dash varies a lot but tends to go up and below 3 TH/s a lot. Currently, the block reward is at (converted) 261.96 USD. It goes down by 7.1% per year. Dash's block time is 3.5 minutes.

Think about it: We can approximate the total money miners make under the assumption that the total hashing power and Dash's value stay about the same as the integral of `261.96 USD * 525600/3.5 * e^(-x*0.0736465)` over `x` from 0 to `r` where `r` is the time in years we regard Note that this isn't exact but using this integral I don't have to calculate weird sums. This means that you'll make about `100 MH/s / (3 TH/s)` of that.

Plug those numbers in and you get that you should make 2438.59 USD during those 2 years.

Now ask yourself this question: Would you sell that for 500 USD or try to keep the 2438.59 USD to you when your operational costs (allegedly) obviously are below 500 USD for that time? And why would the cloud storage provider?

In case you're still interested in the break even point: Just determine `r` for that integral times your share being equal to 500 USD. The result is `r = 0.386758`. So after 4 months and 19.23 days.

Answer (score 0):

A mining contract with HashFlare with 100 MH/s mining power - just like what you ask - will give you 3.6 US$ daily as DASH price is 190$ ([source](https://buydash.net/dash-cloud-mining/)). Currently, you pay for the same contract 580$, meaning you will get your investment back in about six months.

Comment: I know the asker let's you assume that the network's hashrate and the price stay the same, but it would probably be a good improvement to address those assumptions.